# How do I create a react hook that sets up async listener?

Tags: reactjs

How can I create a hook that needs to setup a async event listener.  Essentially I'm using a library with a `listen` function that returns a promise to an function to `unlisten` to the event.

so I'm trying to setup a useEvent hook that takes eventName and callback to be called when the event happens.

what I want is something like this:

```
const useEvent = (eventName, callback) => {
  useEffect(() => {
    const unlisten = await listen(eventName, callback);
    return unlisten
  }
}
```

but I cant easily wrap the await in an inner async function because I need the return value.

what do I do?

Answer (score 1):

You can declare the Promise up front, then wait for it to resolve not in the main effect callback body, but in the cleanup function:

```
const useEvent = (eventName, callback) => {
    useEffect(() => {
        const unlistenProm = listen(eventName, callback);
        return () => {
            unlistenProm.then((unlisten) => {
                unlisten();
            }); // .catch(handleErrors); // ?
        }
    }, [eventName, callback]);
};
```

Comment: `eventName` and `callback` need to be added to `useEffect` dependency array

Comment: Beware of `callback` dependency, which needs to create with `useCallback` to reduce unnecessary updates.